# C# script running execute line when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, plsql

I'm new to programming C#. I've written a script that queries an oracle dB and if the rowcount is > 0, it supposed to run a bat file, but if its not, its supposed to end.

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace trigOra
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=OMP1;User Id=user;Password=pwd;";

            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#

            conn.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cast(Count(*) as varchar(20)) as trig FROM DMSN.DS3R_1XRTT_VOICE_TRIGGER";
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();

            int cnt;
            if (int.TryParse(dr.GetString(0), out cnt))
            {
                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\AutoBatch\backup\trigger.bat");
                    cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE DMSN.DS3R_1XRTT_VOICE_TRIGGER";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            conn.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

The code works except for that it always seems to execute this part:

```
if (cnt > 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\AutoBatch\backup\trigger.bat");
    cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE DMSN.DS3R_1XRTT_VOICE_TRIGGER";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

even though rowcount returned is 0. hmmmm...

Comment: why do you need `cast as varchar`? you can use `dr.GetInt32/64()` instead

Comment: also it seems that you need to use `Process.Start(...).WaitForExit()` otherwise you will run truncate before your backup finishes.

Comment: try initialising int cnt = 0; and then see

Comment: I would suspect your Count is returning more than 0

Comment: no, don't need to use a varchar, went to the varchar method because I couldn't get the data type to flow through in C#.

Comment: Add Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0)); before int cnt; and show us a result.

Comment: @DanilaPolevshikov I got a value back of 0

Comment: Im suprised this even builds, you should be getting a"use of unassigned local variable 'cnt'" or similar

Comment: now when I try this: dr.GetInt64(0) I get a "Enumeration yielded no results" but there are rowcounts in the table, the query I'm using in the script returns a number of 21

Comment: How you determine that IF section is executed? I use you code against SQL server with a fake query "selectcast(Count(*) as varchar(20)) from sys.objects where 1=0" and IF section cnt>0 not fired. Lets add two additional Console.WriteLine: Console.WriteLine("We are inside TryParse ") and Console.WriteLine("We are inside cnt >0")

May be section not fired really but you this it did.

Comment: ok...so I think I know the issue...the truncate command is executing before the .bat file finishes...how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Your bat file must be runned with a WaitForExit() function:

```
int exitCode = RunProcessForExitCode(filename, arguments);

    private static int RunProcessForExitCode(string processFilename, string processArguments)
    {
        //make process output possible to machine-reading
        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = processFilename,
                Arguments = processArguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        Console.Write(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        process.WaitForExit();
        return process.ExitCode;
    }
```